# Use enum for default value of defineProps

Tags: typescript, vue.js, enums, vuejs3, vue-props

This code was working just fine with vue3 and typescript:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue'

enum Position {
  TOP = 'top',
  RIGHT = 'right',
  BOTTOM = 'bottom',
  LEFT = 'left',
}

export default {
  props: {
    position: {
      type: String as PropType<Position>,
      default: Position.BOTTOM,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

But equivalent code in `<script setup>` syntax:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
enum Activator {
    PERSIST = 'persist',
    DEMAND = 'demand',
    HOVER = 'hover'
}

type Props = {
    activator?: Activator
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    activator: Activator.HOVER
});
</script>
```

The script has less boilerplate but also doesn't work with an error:

> Error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] `defineProps()` in  cannot reference locally declared variables because it will be hoisted outside of the setup() function. If your component options require initialization in the module scope, use a separate normal  to export the options instead.
>  
> ```
> App.vue
> 13 |  
> 14 |  const props = withDefaults(defineProps(), {
> 15 |      activator: Activator.HOVER
>    |                 ^^^^^^^^^
> 16 |  });
> 17 |  
>     at Se (https://sfc.vuejs.org/assets/index.8aa136ef.js:137:75)
>     at https://sfc.vuejs.org/assets/index.8aa136ef.js:141:1419
>     at Object.enter (https://sfc.vuejs.org/assets/index.8aa136ef.js:76:6842)
> ```

Isn't it possible to use enums for default value with script setup? [Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UU1PwkAQ/SubvQAJ7UY5WQtCAokeVALG015qO9Bq9yO7U4gh/HenpShCwh42mfdm3pt9u+MTa8NNBTzisU9dYZF5wMqyMtHroeToJR9JDbpSbJJisUnQOLaTmtGZzxbLp+UbG7KOBecLj53+gZnOnicv05rIQCU6O+KPr++zRQ3nZgOuI/Veaqnx2wKbO2M9Ua12cjR7iP6M2/7UaI/MtgPbAvMprJKqRN/NYFVoaLTi5h51e/0LzRPJsFmJhHv3tXQsDinQm6lAULZMEKhiLM5vRjmUpWFb48osFlTXA79NvM8LZY3DQCU2/PRGU6qNtWwJCjM6LiM5xV7XkueI1kdCVNp+rcPUKDEmTrhKY6EgyIwaD8LbcHAnMsr4FA/Bq+DDma0HR46Stzk34oJASjlwoDNw4K6anfX+MzzjLkxrT/qYPd//AJeQyek=)

EDIT: It seems that after I export the type from other files it doesn't crash. I'll investigate a little further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the `enum` in an other (non-setup) script.

```
<script setup lang="ts">


type Props = {
    activator?: Activator
}
  

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    activator:  Activator.HOVER·
});

</script>

<script lang="ts"> // here
enum Activator {
    PERSIST = 'persist',
    DEMAND = 'demand',
    HOVER = 'hover'
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: When I import enum from other file it works, isn't it strange?

Comment: @BT101 Nothing strange. The error explains why this happens. You need to have a clear idea what `script setup` syntax does in order to use it efficiently. It translates defineProps to `props: {}` outside setup function, while the rest of the block goes to `setup() {}`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this synax doesn't support the `enum`s according to [this](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features)

> As of now, the type declaration argument must be one of the following to ensure correct static analysis:
>
> - A type literal
> - A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file

You could use a basic type :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
type Activator = "persist" | "demand" | "hover";
type Props = {
  activator?: Activator;
};

withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  activator: "demand",
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ activator }}</div>
</template>
```